# How to use require in ajax-called file within Wordpress

Tags: ajax, wordpress, require

I'm trying to migrate a complete website to Wordpress, and it went quite well except for the following part ...

I have an AJAX call of a file located in my WP theme like this : *.../wp-content/themes/mytheme/inc/intercom.php*
In this file i have several required files i don't really understand how to call, because the problem is this page (intercom.php) throws an error 500 that seems to come from the 'require' method

All the files i want to call are located in the same folder : *.../wp-content/themes/mytheme/inc/*

Here is some examples of calls on 'class_user.php' i already tried and that don't work :

- `require __DIR__.'/class_user.php';`
- `require get_template_directory().'/inc/class_user.php';`
- `require './class_user.php';`
- `require '/class_user.php';`
- `require 'class_user.php';`

None of the above worked, always the error 500 thrown.

Note that my code looks like this (i cut everything after the calls since it's not relevant here)

```
<?php
require __DIR__.'/functions.php';
require __DIR__.'/class_user.php';
require __DIR__.'/class_support.php'; 
require __DIR__.'/class_admin.php';
$userclass = new GKZ_user();
$sup = new GKZ_support();
$admin = new GKZ_admin();
$response = array();
echo json_encode($response);
```

So basically, my question is how to require/include files, in an ajax-called file that is not a WP page (and won't be) but incorporated in a WP theme ?

Comment: Is that code snippet your functions.php file?

Comment: @KGreene No it's the code snippet of _intercom.php_ file as mentioned